# if statement comparing path with a space AutoHotKey

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

Because of the space in the space I get this error :

> Error: The following variable name contains an illegal character
>   C:\Users\Ko La\Desktop

How can I resolve this?

```
if (%A_ScriptDir%="C:\Users\Ko La\Desktop")
return
else{
MsgBox, 4, , Do you want to rename the files in %A_ScriptDir%? (Press YES or NO)
IfMsgBox No
    return
else{
    MsgBox Rename is done
    return
}
}
```

I also get the same error with when I  use the short name  :

```
if (%A_ScriptDir%="C:\Users\KOLA~1\Desktop")
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: sorry for this, I have edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

Your problem is not the string, its the variable `%A_ScriptDir%`.

In the if it is already a *expression* so `A_ScriptDir` gets replaced with the path and because of the `%` it is **evaluated a second time**, which is of course not possible and throws the error.

## Solution (tl;dr)

Remove the `%` in line 1

```
if (A_ScriptDir="C:\Users\Ko La\Desktop")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which line is throwing the error, I assume you are saying the issue is due to the space in the directory name?   If so, fire up your command line (run cmd.exe) and change to the users directory:

cd \Users

type in:

dir /x

And find the "short" name for the folder.   It is probably:

KOLA~1

Replace your first line with:

if (%A_ScriptDir%="C:\Users\KOLA~1\Desktop")

[or whatever the "short name" for the directory is]

Comment: Thanks @alfreema, I tried with the short name but I am style getting the same error

Comment: if (%A_ScriptDir%="\Users\KOLA~1\Desktop")